# Serialisation and deserialization of objects using Kiota Graph SDK for DotNet

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, kiota

I'm trying to serialise and de-serialise a non IParsable object which has enclosed IParsable objects, using graph sdk 5 for dotnet c#. For example my class is

```
public class ReadData
 {
   public Group GroupData { get; set; }
   public Team TeamData { get; set; }
 }
```

Expected json format is graph native format, not sdk dependent json. Graph v5 has introduced some changes like backingstore and odatatype property etc. I'm not interested in these properties in my json.

I've used System.Text.Json.Serialization serialisation/de-serialisation apis, but that's not generating graph native json.

I've tried kiota serialisation apis from JsonParseNode.GetObjectValue to de-serialise (Microsoft.Kiota.Abstractions.Serialization) and  JsonSerializationWriter.WriteObjectValue (Microsoft.Kiota.Serialization.Json). Both of these expecting to have IParsable objects to be serialised/deserialised
Example provided is a simple case. I've complex classes.

Any ideas on how to get this working please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid that your classes need to implement IParsable interface. When using JsonSerializerWriter, have you tried `using var writer = new JsonSerializationWriter(); writer.WriteObjectValue("GroupData", readData.GroupData); writer.WriteObjectValue("TeamData", readData.TeamData);`?

Comment: Hello user2250152, thanks for responding to my queries. Sorry for delay. I've tried implementing IParsable interface before and tested.  Found below issues : If one of the properties is null say TeamData, then serialisation thrown exception. I couldn't find anything to ignore null values on write. Also the josn didn't have property names (GroupData, TeamData). Expected json format is 
 {"GroupData":{"xxx":"yyyy"}} .
Deserilisation also failed with null ref exception. Could you provide some sample code if possible.

Comment: @user2250152 throwing exception during serialisation was an issue in my IParsable implementation. I could do serialise and de-serialise for ReadData. Will be trying this approach for complex data clases I've and update you here. Thanks .

Comment: @user2250152 I've implemented IParsable interface for all classes and that helped me. Thanks for your help!.